# How do I get a single percentage/proportion plot using ggplot for separate groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df <- data.frame(k = sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE),
g = sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7)))
```

In this data frame I have two groups g which members are in one of three conditions k.

Now, I want to see the proportions of the conditions k in both groups.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = k, fill = as.factor(g), y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
    geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

That looks nice at first but there is a problem. The group 2 is larger than group 1. Therefore the proportions are not right: It looks as if all conditions were more likely in group 2 than in group 1. I need to calculate the `y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)` for both groups separately. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  count(k) %>%
  mutate(share = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = k, fill = as.factor(g), y = share)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

Comment: That would return the proportions for each condition, not for each group. I switched to `group_by(g)` and `count(k)`.

Comment: @Markus Ah, my bad. I've switched g and k in the answer.

Comment: in case this solution does no work for anybody, try dplyr::count().